# Webdriver Unable to click hover over button for FireFox in Java

Tags: java, mouseover, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a hover over 'edit' button. However, I keep getting "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" Error when I use mouseOverElement. 
Any idea on how to make it work? Thanks

< div class="editbox" > 
 < h2>Title< /h2> 
  < ul> 
    < li > 
       < small class="editlinks" > 
            **< a class="edit" href="#">Edit< / a >** 
       < /small> 
     < strong> Content  
    < /li> 
  < /ul> 
< /div>

Here is my code:

***Approach 1:***

WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.editbox ul li")); 
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.editbox ul li small.editlinks a.edit")); 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
builder.moveToElement(textArea).build().perform(); 
timer.wait(5000); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.editbox ul li small.editlinks a.edit")).clik();

***Approach 2:***

Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
builder.moveToElement(textArea); 
timer.wait(5000); 
builder.click(button); 
builder.build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

I'm using to following code to hover over an element:

```
if (element instanceof Locatable) {
    Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
    hoverItem.getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView();
    Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) webDriver).getMouse(); 
    mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
}
```

Try if it works.

I'm not sure you can click on that `li` element, since it is invisible. Shouldn't you hover your link (`a` tag)?

Comment: However, a tag is a hidden button. I need to hover over to the li element in order to make the edit button visible. is there any way to do it? thanks

Comment: Normally, if you inspect the element with Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug, the element will be grayed out if invisible. Did you try the above code to hover?

Comment: I tried to use the above code. but the element is still not showing up for click.

Comment: @asgoth : I tried the above code and it is working fine for chrome -v26.x.xx browser. But fails in FF- v11.0 and IE- v8(64Bit). Is anything i've to do to work on other browsers? Is any other solution to resolve this issue? Let me know i am struggling with this issue for a long peroid